XML - Foreach mostra apenas o primeiro resultado
tenho esse codigo em xml
<estoque>
<veiculo>
<id>649033</id>
<anunciante_id>750</anunciante_id>
<kilometragem>160000</kilometragem>
<valor_final>22900</valor_final>
<valor_de/>
<financiamento_entrada/>
<financiamento_parcelas/>
<financiamento_valor_parcela/>
<placa>EYM9259</placa>
<observacao>
UNO WAY 2012 - REPASSE! Ideal para quem busca um carro de trabalho confiável e econômico, o Uno Way 2012 está pronto para Mecânica OK – Carro Super Econômico – **EspEspaço Versátil– Consulte condições de compra, troca e financiamento com nossos consultores . COMPRE, VENDA, TROQUE E FINANCIE SEU CARRO COM AGILIDADE.
</observacao>
<link/>
<tipo_id>29</tipo_id>
<tipo_descricao>Carro</tipo_descricao>
<marca_id>1299</marca_id>
<marca_descricao>FIAT</marca_descricao>
<modelo_id>3227</modelo_id>
<modelo_descricao>UNO</modelo_descricao>
<versao_id>16860</versao_id>
<versao_descricao> 1.0 EVO WAY 8V FLEX 2P MANUAL </versao_descricao>
<ano_fabricacao_id>51912</ano_fabricacao_id>
<ano_fabricacao_descricao>2012</ano_fabricacao_descricao>
<ano_modelo_id>51912</ano_modelo_id>
<ano_modelo_descricao>2012</ano_modelo_descricao>
<cor_id>4</cor_id>
<cor_descricao>Prata</cor_descricao>
<combustivel_id>6</combustivel_id>
<combustivel_descricao>Gasolina e álcool</combustivel_descricao>
<categoria_id/>
<categoria_descricao/>
<porta_id>2</porta_id>
<porta_descricao>2</porta_descricao>
<cambio_id>4</cambio_id>
<cambio_descricao>Manual</cambio_descricao>
<blindagem_id>1</blindagem_id>
<blindagem_descricao>Veículo não blindado</blindagem_descricao>
<situacao_veiculo_id>1</situacao_veiculo_id>
<situacao_veiculo_descricao>Segundo dono ou mais</situacao_veiculo_descricao>
<situacao_anuncio_id>1</situacao_anuncio_id>
<situacao_anuncio_descricao>Ativo</situacao_anuncio_descricao>
<data_inclusao>2024-10-28 11:26:29</data_inclusao>
<data_modificaco>2024-11-06 10:55:15</data_modificaco>
<chassi/>
<opcionais>
<opcional>
<opcional_id>15</opcional_id>
<opcional_descricao>Som</opcional_descricao>
</opcional>
</opcionais>
<fotos>
<imagem>
http://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/elasticbeanstalk-sa-east-1-847031601019/upload/649033_5742849.jpeg
</imagem>
<imagem>
http://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/elasticbeanstalk-sa-east-1-847031601019/upload/649033_5742855.jpeg
</imagem>
<imagem>
http://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/elasticbeanstalk-sa-east-1-847031601019/upload/649033_5742850.jpeg
</imagem>
<imagem>
http://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/elasticbeanstalk-sa-east-1-847031601019/upload/649033_5742851.jpeg
</imagem>
<imagem>
http://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/elasticbeanstalk-sa-east-1-847031601019/upload/649033_5742852.jpeg
</imagem>
<imagem>
http://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/elasticbeanstalk-sa-east-1-847031601019/upload/649033_5742853.jpeg
</imagem>
<imagem>
http://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/elasticbeanstalk-sa-east-1-847031601019/upload/649033_5742854.jpeg
</imagem>
<imagem>
http://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/elasticbeanstalk-sa-east-1-847031601019/upload/649033_5742856.jpeg
</imagem>
<imagem>
http://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/elasticbeanstalk-sa-east-1-847031601019/upload/649033_5742857.jpeg
</imagem>
<imagem>
http://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/elasticbeanstalk-sa-east-1-847031601019/upload/649033_5742858.jpeg
</imagem>
<imagem>
http://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/elasticbeanstalk-sa-east-1-847031601019/upload/649033_5742859.jpeg
</imagem>
</fotos>
</veiculo>
</estoque>

Porem qdo faço o forech das "FOTOS" ele me retorna apenas a primeira imagem
$xml = simplexml_load_file("../teste/xml/arquivo.xml") or die ("Error: Cannot create object");


    foreach ($xml->veiculo as $registro) {
        
        $imgs = $registro->fotos;
        
        foreach($imgs as $img){
            echo $img->imagem;
    

